# swift: what is the correct way of working with current location

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I am quite new to swift and IOS development.

I would like to ask experienced members what is the correct way of creating mapvie and tableview in one viewcontroller and populating them.

[image]

The logic of application is the following:

- get current location of user
- read plist file with POI coordinates
- for each POI run a function wich calculates distance between user and point
- populate table with data from plist file plus newly calculated data.

Both mapview and tableview are in the same viewcontroller.

in viewDidLoad I am getting users location.

in viewwillappear I am running functions to read plist file and calculate distances between POIs and user.

Everything is working but it is not stable ... sometimes it might show user's location but table will be empty. So I doubt that I am doing everything correctly. Also probably it is not correct to put both map and table inside one class?

*Update*
Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var theMapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var branches = [Branch]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()

        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }






            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self


            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()


            //mapview setup to show user location
            theMapView.delegate = self
            theMapView.showsUserLocation = true
            theMapView.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
            theMapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 2)! 
    }



    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        readFromPlist()

    }






    //MARK: UITableView methods
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return branches.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: MapCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mapCell") as! MapCustomCell
        let brnch = branches[indexPath.row]
        cell.mapSetupCell(brnch.cityName, AddressLabel: brnch.address, DistanceLabel: brnch.distance)
        return cell
    }



    //MARK: FUNC TO CALCULATE DISTANCE
    func calculateDistance (lat1 lat1: Double, lon1: Double, lat2: Double, lon2: Double) -> String {

        return "100km"
    }



    func locationManager (manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let myCoordinates = locations.last
        let myLat = myCoordinates!.coordinate.latitude
        let myLong = myCoordinates!.coordinate.longitude

        let myCoordinates2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLat, myLong)

        let myLatDelta = 0.10
        let myLongDelta = 0.10
        let mySpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(myLatDelta, myLongDelta)

        let myRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myCoordinates2D, span: mySpan)

        theMapView.setRegion(myRegion, animated: true)

        let myAnno = MKPointAnnotation()
        myAnno.coordinate = myCoordinates2D

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
        print("error:" + error.localizedDescription)
    }



    func readFromPlist() {

        //read plist file to extract banks coordinates
        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("poi", ofType: "plist")
        let POIarrays = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

        for arr in POIarrays! {

            var ctName : String!
            var brnchAddress : String!
            var wrkngHours : String!
            var lat : Double!
            var long : Double!

            ctName  = arr.objectForKey("cityName")! as! String
            brnchAddress  = arr.objectForKey("address")! as! String
            wrkngHours  = arr.objectForKey("workingHours")! as! String
            lat  = Double(arr.objectForKey("latitude")! as! String)
            long  = Double(arr.objectForKey("longitude")! as! String)


                let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = lat
                let longitude : CLLocationDegrees = long

                let bankLocation : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)


                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = bankLocation
                annotation.title = bnkName
                annotation.subtitle = brnchAddress

                self.theMapView.addAnnotation(annotation)


                let myLatitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude
                let myLongitude = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude

                if myLatitude != nil {

                    let dist = calculateDistance(lat1: latitude, lon1: longitude, lat2: myLatitude!, lon2: myLongitude!)

                    let b = Branch(cityName: ctName!, address: brnchAddress!, distance: dist)

                    branches.append(b)

            }
        }

    }


}
```

Sometimes I got an error "error:The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)" and current location doesn't appear on my map.

Comment: Please show your code, so we will have a better understanding of what could be going wrong, and we will be happy to help!

Comment: Getting the users location isn't a one-time thing.  The users location will change over time and will get more accurate in the first 30 seconds or so. As Jake says, show your code. How are you getting the location?  On iOS 9 you can use `requestLocation` but on earlier versions you will need to get several location updates and check the `horizontalAccuracy`

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW9.

Comment: @Paulw11 that is the point. I think sometimes it takes some time to find location and execution runs forward without populating array for the table. Also sometime I got an error "error:The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"

Comment: You should call `readFromPlist()` at the end of your `didUpdateLocations` method.  Currently your table won't show anything if you don't get a location until after `viewWillAppear` is called.

Comment: You should either request when in use or always authorisation.  In your didUpdateLocations method you shouldn't call `stopUpdatingLocation`. The real world is messy. Location isn't precise, especially the first fix. As I said ios9 provides a nice "requestLocation" method that will give you a single, accurate location (if it can, location isn't always available e.g. Indoors) but ios8 you need to do the work yourself;  your table distance calculations need to be recalculated when you get a new location; calculate the distance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and reload the table when Location updates

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for information about new method I will read more about it

Comment: @JakeBraden I have added my code do you have any thoughts on the topic?